# DI & MVC: What's the point of dependency injection in controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, dependency-injection

***Short ver***

Sometimes I see a piece of code where a dependency is injected into the constructor of a controller, but what advantage does it offer?

***Long ver***

Let's assume that you're seeing code like the following one.

```
//ASP.NET
public class SampleController : Controller 
{
    private IDependency dependency;

    public SampleController(IDependency dependency) 
    {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }
}
```

Or, if you prefer PHP, let's have a look at the following one

```
//PHP with Laravel
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class SampleController extends Controller
{
    private $dependency;

    public function __construct(Dependency $dependency)
    {
        $this->dependency = $dependency;
    }
}
```

As far as I know, Dependency Injection is meant to ***decouple a client from its dependency***, so that...

1. the client can use different dependencies at run time (with a setter method)
2. updating the dependency class is less likely to force you to update the client too

...etc.

However, controllers are not instantiated,

```
$service = new Service();
$controller = new Controller($service);
//you don't do such a thing, do you?
```

....nor do controllers use setter functions (usually).

Nonetheless, I still see this approach on the internet, including [ASP.NET's doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Is it really beneficial to inject a dependency into a controller rather than instantiating a class within the constructor with the `new` keyword? (If so, how does this approach improve your code?)

Comment: What do you mean *"controllers are not instantiated"*? You might not write that code explicitly, unless you're e.g. newing one up in a test, but they will absolutely be instantiated (via the DI container) when the app is running. Why do you think the value of DI in controller classes is different to the value of DI anywhere else?

Answer (score 2):

Ok,

So when using DI, you are usually injecting an Interface into your controller right?

What if you want to swap out the implementation of it? 
For example you have a `ISearchApi`, currently you have it setup in your DI code that `ISearchApi`'s implementation is `GoogleApi`, now you want to swap it to `BingApi`. You do not have to touch any of your existing code since it's all been abstracted behind an interface.  This is part of the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://stackify.com/dependency-inversion-principle/).

What if you implementation of `BingApi` also expects another class in it's constructor? and that class also expects more classes in it's constructor like this:

```
new BingApi(new BingControls(new Api(new HttpClient, "ApiKey")));
```

This is going to be very difficult to maintain going forward, where if it was correctly setup in your DI container then you would not need to worry about this.

Another reason would be for unit testing. I'm not going to get into the debate on what Controllers should do in regards to logic. But it would be a lot more difficult to unit test a controller that is expecting a concrete implementation, especially if that implementation calls any services/databases. There would be no way to mock that out since the controllers is just `new`ing it up.

The only downside I can see to dependency injection is that there is slightly more code to write when the application starts up. But that is very minor in consideration to what the benefits offer.